# jQuery: validation with ajax

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) on a form loaded via ajax.

For whatever reason, it isn't working.  Is there something special I need to do b/c it's loaded after js is initialized?  Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Using the code from the plugin site:

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("form").validate();
});
```

Comment: When are you calling `validate()`? It's hard to fix your code without seeing it.

Comment: You're right, Craig.  I've tried several things--including copy/paste the demos from the plugin site.  I can get it to work w/o the ajax, but it's a problem with ajax loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a form via AJAX, you can't use a `ready` event, because that only runs when the page initially loads. Instead, use the loaded callback, e.g.:

```
$("#formDiv").load("/Path/To/Form", function() { 
    $("#formDiv form").validate();
});
```

This ensures `validate()` is called *after* the AJAX call returns.